# Animated timelapse heatmap on world map query

Tags: r, heatmap, gganimate, rworldmap

Hi there I am trying to create an animated heatmap of CO2 emissions over time on a world map with a result something similar to this (https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/annual-co2-emissions-per-country?tab=map&time=1846).
After a few attempts my approach has been to use the rworldmap and gganimate packages to firstly merge my CO2 emissions data (three columns 'Country' 'Year' 'CO2 Emissions') with the map data, secondly create an initial plot of the first year of data (1850) and then animate it.

I am struggling to make the initial plot as i suspect my combined map and CO2 data, merged by the line of code:
`CO2_data_with_map \<- joinCountryData2Map(CO2_data_filtered,    joinCode = "NAME", nameJoinColumn = "Country")`
has not merged effectively.
This is the current code which is not yielding an initial plot:
`num_colors <- 5 CO2_color_scale <- brewer.pal(num_colors,    "Spectral")`

```
initial_year <- min(CO2_data_with_map$Year)

`p <- ggplot() +

geom_polygon(data = CO2_data_with_map, aes(x = long, y = lat,         group = group, fill = `CO2 emissions`)) +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = CO2_color_scale, name = "CO2        Emissions") +
labs(title = paste0("Year: ", prettyNum(initial_year, big.mark =        ","))) +
theme_map() +
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold", margin =          margin(0,0,10,0)))`
```

when I print(p) I receive error code:
`Error in` geom_polygon()`: ! Problem while computing aesthetics. ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer. Caused by error in` FUN()`: ! object 'CO2 emissions' not found Run` rlang::last_trace() `to see where the error occurred.`

but when I run names(CO2_data_with_map) CO2 emissions is one of many columns.

Can anyone help by either suggesting a fix or different approach, it would be greatly appreciated, please ask if you need any more code

Comment: What does `names(CO2_data_with_map)` return, like the exact output.

Comment: In one section of your code `CO2 emissions` is lower case, and in another section `CO2 Emissions` is capitalized.

Comment: Thank you for replies after reconsideration I have approached the problem using the following code:

Comment: map_final <- CO2_data_clean3 %>%
  right_join(world, by= c(mapname = "region")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(long, lat, 
             group= group, 
             fill= CO2_emissions)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "white", 
               size = 0.01)

Comment: theme_void() +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "B",
                     name= "Years",
                     guide = guide_colorbar(
                       direction = "horizontal",
                       barheight = unit(2, units = "mm"),
                       barwidth = unit(100, units = "mm"),
                       draw.ulim = FALSE,
                       title.position = "top",
                       title.hjust = 0.5,
                       title.vjust = 0.5 ))

Comment: theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5),
    plot.caption = element_text(size = 8, hjust = 1)    legend.position = "bottom") +
  coord_fixed (ratio = 1.3) +
  transition_manual(year)

Comment: while this is sucesfull in making dataframe map_final, when I enter the code to make the animation: animate(map_final, 
        fps = 10, 
        height = 500, 
        width = 700) I receive an error:

Comment: Error in data.frame(previous_frame = c("", all_frames[-length(all_frames)]),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0. Do you have any idea how I would go about solving this?